# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) when I try to decode document fromo firebase

Tags: swift, completion

in my app, I am trying to decode data from the firebase document to the User object but I am receiving the next code error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

[image: code]

the app does not crush, so it keeps in a loop there.

The app is built with MVVM - service - repository pattern and the problem could be the nested completions or the background call to firebase, I don't know it.

The ViewModel calls the service layer where the business logic is implemented, and the service call to the repository layer brings the data from firebase.
the code is the following bellow:

```
func loadAllUsers(completion : @escaping (Result<[User], UserRepositoryError>) -> Void) {

        usersRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error  {
                 print( "debug: Error getting documents: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                print( "debug: No documents found")
                return
            }

            var users = [User]()

            for document in documents {
                let id = document.documentID
                let data = document.data()
                let location: GeoPoint = data["location"] as! GeoPoint
                let name = data["name"] as! String
                let profileImageData = data["profileImageData"] as! Data
                let surname = data["surname"] as! String
                let products: [Product] = data["products"] as! [Product]

                let user = User(id:id ,name: name, surname: surname, products: products, location: location, profileImageData: profileImageData)
                users.append(user)
            }
            completion(.success(users))
        }
}
```

this is not a good way to decode a document but in this way we can see with more details where the code fails, right now I´m getting the same issue at:

> let data = document.data()

Comment: Unrelated, but it's the second time I see it in two days: Why use `if let ... = try? ...` in a `do`/`catch`? If there was a real thrown error, it be better to have that error rather than the text with no real explanation.

Comment: I have updated the code but the same is happening. there is an infinity loop with the last error shown.

Comment: There is an infinite loop? What loop, a call stack loop?

Comment: de debugger enters the first image in the question body with the error indefinitely.

Comment: I have edited the question. new code